# How do i get the date counter to stop running in background even while paused? Any and all help is appreciated

Tags: javascript

I have a date counter with play/pause button that works great, however, during pause the counter continues to run in the background.

To see what I mean, press pause, wait 10 seconds, press play and you will see the date has advanced 1 or 2 months, not to the next day. I am grateful for any help. My code is below.

```js
var virtualOrigin = Date.parse("2020-01-01"),
    realOrigin = Date.now(),
    factor = 862350;

function getVirtual(time) {
    return new Date(virtualOrigin + (time - realOrigin) * factor);
}

function format(time) {
    var month = time.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = time.getDate();
    if (month < 10) {
        month = '0' + month;
    }
    if (day < 10) {
        day = '0' + day;
    }
    return (month) +
        "-" + day +
        "-" + time.getFullYear();
}
var output = document.getElementById("txt");
var t = 0;
var flagTimer = 'startTime()';

function pause() {
    if (flagTimer == 'startTime()') {
        clearTimeout(t);
        document.getElementById('Pause').value = "Play";
        flagTimer = 'pause';
    } else {
        flagTimer = 'startTime()';
        document.getElementById('Pause').value = "Pause";
        startTime();
    }
}

function startTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    var display = getVirtual(now);
    output.innerText = format(display);
    t = setTimeout(startTime, 1000 / factor - (now.getMilliseconds() %
        (1000 / factor)));
}

function clickEvent() {
    pause();
}
```

```css
.txt {
 color: orange;
 margin-left: 46%;
 margin-top: 10%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 300;
}

#Pause {
 margin-left: 47.6%;
 margin-top: 10%;
 border: 2px solid orange;
 color: blue;
 display: block;
 width: 55px;
 text-align: center;
}

#Pause:hover {
 background-color: orange;
 color: white;
 border: 2px solid lightblue;
}

#toggle-animation {
 margin-left: 45.5%;
 margin-top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>timer8</title>
    <meta charset=UTF-8>
  </head>
  <body onload="startTime()">
    <input type="button" id="Pause" class="toggle-animation" value="Pause" onclick="clickEvent();" />
    <div id="txt" class="txt"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please format your code with proper indentation ; as it is currently written, it's pretty hard to read.

Comment: why while-loop or date as tags ??? seriously !?

Answer (score 0):

Your function to calculate the virtual date:

```
  function getVirtual(time) {
    return new Date( virtualOrigin + (time - realOrigin) * factor );
  }
```

... calculates it based on the difference between the current time and page load time, regardless of whether you have paused or not.

You could fix this by:

- when pausing, updating `virtualOrigin` to the current virtual datetime
- in your getVirtual(time) function, only adding the difference when your timer is unpaused
- when unpausing, updating `realOrigin` to the current real datetime.

Comment: Thx for lightning response. Been trying since to implement, but to no avail. I'm not well read in js and was hoping you could spell it out for me. I think you mean in pause() under "if" adding virtualOrigin= something(current virtual date time), and in "else" adding realOrigin= something(current real date time). Unable to figure out the something. I appreciate your help!